# correct using Promise.all for more http request

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I would like to have two HTTP request for obtain first the list of Items(in Json) and the second request the Item that user have selected.
But when I try to run the code, the console displays the following error:

**response getItems {with the JSON array}**

**response getTipology undefined**

**Promise getItems & getTipology:{2 array, the first is correct and the second is undefined}**

I'm new to Angular but could some one please help me with this. Thanks

```
item: any;
    onItemChanged: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    items: any[];
    onItemsChanged: BehaviorSubject<any>;

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any
        {
            this.routeParams = route.params;

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                Promise.all([
                    this.getItems(),
                    this.getTipology()
                ]).then((result) => { // Success
                        console.log('Promise getItems & getTipology:', result);
                        resolve();
                    },
                    msg => { // Error
                        reject(msg);
                    }
                );
            });
        }


getTipology(): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._httpClient.get('https://www.andreabandiera.it/get_tipology_by_id.php?ID=' + this.routeParams.id)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    this.item = response[1];
                    this.onItemChanged.next(this.item);
                    resolve(response[1]);
                    console.log('response getTipology', this.item);
                }, reject);
        });
    }



getItems(): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._httpClient.get('https://www.andreabandiera.it/get_tipology.php')
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    this.items = response[0];
                    this.onItemsChanged.next(this.items);
                    resolve(response[0]);
                    console.log('response getItems', this.items);
                }, reject);
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you check how Angular works ? what you are trying to do is really going in circles. I would recommend to go to angular.io read about it and revisit the development all will be clear. :D

Answer (score 3):

`promises` are essentially obsolete and `observables` should be used in their place because they are more modern and flexible. First off don't wrap an observable within a promise. Call [toPromise()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) on the observable to convert it to a promise. I really recommend you try using `observables` instead of `promises` like so:

```
forkJoin(
    this._httpClient.get('https://www.andreabandiera.it/get_tipology.php'),
    this._httpClient.get('https://www.andreabandiera.it/get_tipology_by_id.php?ID=' + this.routeParams.id)
).subscribe((results) => {
    // access tipology via results[0] and the item via results[1]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong how you are doing things, but i would strongly suggest using observables to do this. Angular's httpclient works 100% on observables and is pretty straight forward once you get it.

With observables its possible to concatenate, merge, switch and a lot of other operations that can be found out in [rxjs docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/).

I would suggest some refactoring on your code:

1. Change `getTipology` and `getItems` methods so they return the actual `this._httpClient.get` function call, without its subscription.

```
getTipology() {
  return this._httpClient.get('https://www.andreabandiera.it/get_tipology_by_id.php?ID=' + this.routeParams.id);
}
```

2. Subscribe to both at the same place (forward explication) and manage data at the subscription or take a look into observable pipes, which its possible to handle data accordingly per function.
3. It isnt clear to me if what you are looking for is a parallel or a operation where the second request depends on the response of the first one (waterfall). For a parallel request i would suggest taking a look into [rxjs.forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) or for the waterfall condition perhaps [rxjs.switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) can do the trick.

Let me know if this workout for you.